# Improving Weighted Moving Average Performance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been playing around with a pandas data frame with 414,000 rows.

Built into pandas is an exponential moving average computed by:

```
series.ewm(span=period).mean()
```

The above executes in < 0.3 seconds. I am however in search of trying to use a weighted moving average (which has a linear linear weighting of each element). I came across the following function:

```
def WMA(self, s, period):
    return s.rolling(period).apply(lambda x: (np.arange(period)+1*x).sum()/(np.arange(period)+1).sum(), raw=True)
```

The **above function took 27 seconds** to execute. I noticed the arange function could be cached and produced the following:

```
def WMA(self, s, period):
    weights = np.arange(period)+1
    weights_sum = weights.sum()
    return s.rolling(period).apply(lambda x: (weights*x).sum()/weights_sum, raw=True)
```

The above function took **11 seconds**, which is a noticeable improvement.

What I'm trying to figure out is if there is some way I can further optimize this (ideally replace the apply function) but genuinely am not sure how to go about it.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? My idea is to use vectorization instead of the apply function.

Comment: @Jannik so df1['randNumCol'] = np.random.randint(0,5, size=400000) and then modify apply the moving average to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `np` sliding window function [docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html), then it looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(500_000))) # x=500_000

p = 50
w = np.arange(p)+1
w_s = w.sum()

########## for comparison purpose ##########
# 1.47 s ± 12.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 2 loops each)
r = d1.rolling(p).apply(lambda x: (w*x).sum()/w_s, raw=True)

# 62.1 ms ± 4.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 2 loops each)
swv = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(d1.values.flatten(), window_shape=p)
sw = (swv*w).sum(axis=1) / w_s

########## for comparison purpose ##########
np.array_equal(r.iloc[p - 1:].values.flatten(), sw) # True
```

So, an overall speedup of `~23.67x`. However, you need to adjust the shape to your desired shape afterwards. Since `sw` starts at `0` with a shape of `x-p`. Whereas `r` starts at `p`, with a shape of `x` and the first `p` values `-> nan`.

Answer (score 1):

Skeletor above was right on the money and I adapted it slightly to handle the issues with `nan`

```
    # THIS USES LOWER LEVEL NUMPY TO GREATLY SPEED IT UP!
    def WMA(self, s, period):
        w = np.arange(period)+1
        w_s = w.sum()   
        swv = sliding_window_view(s.values.flatten(), window_shape=period)
        sw = (swv * w).sum(axis=1) / w_s

        # Need to now return it as a normal series
        sw = np.concatenate((np.full(period - 1, np.nan), sw))
        return pd.Series(sw)
```

**dropped it from 11 seconds down to 1.5 seconds which is much better!**

Comment: Perfect, that's a nice improvement, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [parallel-pandas](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-pandas/) library. With its help, you can parallelize the `apply` method of a sliding window.
Just two extra lines of code if you count library imports)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import monotonic
from parallel_pandas import ParallelPandas


def WMA(s, period):
    weights = np.arange(period) + 1
    weights_sum = weights.sum()
    return s.rolling(period).apply(lambda x: (weights * x).sum() / weights_sum, raw=True)


def parallel_wma(s, period):
    weights = np.arange(period) + 1
    weights_sum = weights.sum()
    # p_apply is parallel apply method
    return s.rolling(period).p_apply(lambda x: (weights * x).sum() / weights_sum, raw=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # initialize parallel-pandas
    ParallelPandas.initialize(n_cpu=16, disable_pr_bar=True)
    
    #create series of length 500 000
    s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 5, size=500_000))
    period = 50

    start = monotonic()
    res = WMA(s, period)
    print(f'synchronous wma time took: {monotonic() - start:.2f} s.')

    start = monotonic()
    res2 = parallel_wma(s, period)
    print(f'parallel wma time took: {monotonic() - start:.2f} s.')
```

```
Output:
   synchronous wma time took: 1.16 s.
   parallel wma time took: 0.22 s.
```

Total speedup: `1.16/0.22 ~ 5.3` and close to the performance on `numpy` arrays that demonstrated Skeletor